# how event loop exactly executes code in 2 seconds if the code is larger and call stack is not empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop, single-threaded

many explanations talk about call-stack being empty, but I don't get it, if we set a timer for 2 second and executes the code in an asynchronous manner, what if I have a code with run time of 10 sec and call-stack is not empty, will the callback function in the callback queue waits for 11 sec to be executed?

Comment: "will the callback function in the callback queue waits for 11 sec to be executed?" - yes, well, if you mean "after the 10 seconds" with it. This is easy to test btw: `let start = performance.now(); setTimeout(() => void console.log(\`timer executed after ${performance.now() - start}ms.\`), 2000); while(performance.now() - start < 10000); console.log('busy waiting finished.');`

Comment: I completely understand wanting to check the underlying theory, but it's still worth doing (and sharing) your empirical test of your thought -- e.g., code doing it and observing how long it takes for the timer to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Imagine this code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hi');
}, 0);

let i = 0;

while (i <= 1e9) {
  i++;
}
```

What happens here?

The code inside `setTimeout` is "postponed" to be run after 0ms "after the current call stack is empty".

But the current script must finish its loop. So if you run this code, it will wait until `i` is counted to 1e9 before logging "hi" to the console.

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/pooriam/nxodhf60/1/)

Comment: @RahulRNair You're welcome. I appreciate it if you mark it as the accepted answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

> ...will the callback function in the callback queue waits for 11 sec to be executed?

Not necessarily 11 seconds, no; it'll run soon after the 10-second synchronous code completes. The length of the timer doesn't matter if it's shorter than the synchronous code duration. More details in [this page](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) on how the Node.js event loop works.

For example, with this code:

```
function elapsed(start) {
    const elapsed = Date.now() - start;
    return `${(elapsed / 1000).toFixed(4)}s`;
}
const startTimer = Date.now();
console.log(`Starting timer`);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Timer fired after ${elapsed(startTimer)}`);
}, 2000);
const finish = Date.now() + 10000;
const startBusyWait = Date.now();
console.log(`Starting to wait`);
while (Date.now() < finish) {
    // Busy-wait -- DON'T DO THIS
}
console.log(`Done busy-waiting after ${elapsed(startBusyWait)}`);
```

you'll see something like:

```
Starting timer
Starting to wait
Done busy-waiting after 10.0000s
Timer fired after 10.0050s
```